# How to form a Regex to get the numbers from a giving string with certain conditions

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a string like this
`(THQ836721='Yes' and BRQ836716='Yes') or (BRQ836717='Yes') and (THQ836728='Yes' and BRQ836756='Yes') or (BRQ836117='Yes') and (SYSQ123='No')`

I need a Reg Ex to get the numbers after THQ,BRQ and SYSQ
My string may smaller or shorter or may have any times of this THQ,BRQ or SYSQ.
So please help to form a Reg eXpression to get the numbers .
The length of numbers may vary
I am using VB.Net in VS2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
(?<=THQ|BRQ|SYSQ)\d+
```